# Resolving small file issue in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am reading from a partitioned table that has close to 4 billion records. 
The files that I am reading from is my source, and I have no control over it to alter the records.

While reading the files through dataframes, for each partition I am creating 2000 files of size less than 2KB. This is because of shuffle partition being set to 2000, to increase the execution speed.

Approach followed to resolve this issue:

I have looped over the HDFS path of the table, post its execution is completed as has created a list with data paths `[/dv/hdfs/..../table_name/partition_value=01,/dv/hdfs/..../table_name/partition_value=02..]`

For each such path, I have calculated 
disk usage and block size from cluster and got the appropriate number of partitions as
`no_of_partitions = ceil[disk_usage / block size]`, and then written the data into another location with the same partition_id such as `[/dv/hdfs/..../table2_name/partition_value=01]`.

Now though this works in reducing the small files to avg block size of 82 MB from 2KB, it is taking about 2.5 mins per partition. With 256 such partitions being available, it is taking more than 10hrs to finish the execution.

Kindly suggest any other method where this could be achieved in less than 2 hrs of time.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have 2000 shuffle partitions you can and should control the output files.
Generating small files in spark is itself a performance degradation for the next read operations.

Now to control small files issue you can do the following:

While writing the dataframe to hdfs repartition it based on the number of partitions and controlling the number of output files per partition

```
df.repartition(partition_col).write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100000).partition_by(partition_col).parquet(path)
```

This will generate files having 100000 records each in every partition. Hence solving your small files issue. This will improve overall read and write performance of your job.

Hope it helps.